# is it possible to use a NPM (a module has made by angular 8 and converted to NPM) in javascript or even react native?

Tags: javascript, angular, react-native, npm

I've made an Angular (v8) module and want to convert it to NPM to use it as a library (package) in a normal JavaScript app (or even in react or react native app).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, right out of the box, React and Angular are very different frameworks.  They don't just interop with each other.